# How to select dates in SQLite with python

Tags: python, sqlite

Im trying to query a table, and need to grab all products that have a date = today date.
Below is my code so far

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import date

date = date.today()
con = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor()

date = date.today()

sql_q = f'''SELECT date, name FROM table WHERE date = {date}'''

table = cur.execute(sql_q)

for row in table:
    print(row)
```

i am using an SQlite 3 db and all data has been entered with the following format:
2022-09-20

However this variable type does not seem to work with SQL.
i know the SQL code should look somthing like this

```
SELECT name FROM test WHERE date = '2022-09-20'
```

but i'd like the date to be selected automatically from python rather than typing it in manually.

Comment: Convert the date to string in a required fromat, i.e. `date = datetime.datetime.strftime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")` and then pass it into the query.

Comment: `date` is a datetime obj already so `date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` is all that's required.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `date()` to get the current date:

```
SELECT name FROM test WHERE date = date()
```

or `CURRENT_DATE`:

```
SELECT name FROM test WHERE date = CURRENT_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to convert date to string and then pass it in query.
maybe your datatype of column and date.today() is different.

```
date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

try using this.